# How to get count of another collection mongoose aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections. I want to get counts of collection2 documents where collection from document match with _id of collection1

```
collection1 = {
    _id:"",
    "name":"",
    "code":""
}

collection2 = {
    _id:"",
    "collection":"<_id of collection1>",
    "subject":""
}
```

How can I get the following output using aggregate :

output:

```
[
 {
   "_id":"<_id of collection1>",
   "all keys of collection1",
   "count":"<count of documents which have collection = _id(collection1) >"
 },
 {
   "_id":"<_id of collection1>",
   "all keys of collection1",
   "count":"<count of documents which have collection = _id(collection1) >"
 }
]
```

My collections:

```
shows= {
    _id:"",
    movie:{type:String},
}

Ticket = {
    show:{type:String, index:true, ref:'shows'}
}
```

These are my actual collections. I need to find tickets count for every shows.